# Why assert expends gas while require does not? (My intuition says te opposite is true)

Tags: error, exceptions, dos

Since `assert` corresponds to **conditions that must never happen if the smart-contract code is correct** my intuition tells me that someone calling an smart-contract that raises an assert must never be "punished" with gas expenditure since caller was not to fault. (Maybe nodes ought to black-list smart-contracts raising asserts and/or a mechanism be in place to allow to redirect new version/patched contracts with no assert).

On the opposite `require` corresponds to **checks on the input data to functions**, so my intuition tells me that invocation with incorrect data ought to be punished.

I think there is something I do NOT understand, or I just completely misunderstood the original intention of `assert` vs `require`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Also, as I see it, an Ethereum attacker aware of code that evaluates to false for a require for a range of input values, can easily prepare sort-of DoS"? What form would such a DoS attack take? Who would benefit and who would be hurt?

Comment: @smarx I'll just removed this part, to make my original post more specific

Answer (score 1):

A failed transaction always costs the sender gas. If it didn't, anyone could mount a denial of service attack against the network by submitting a lot of failing transactions for free.

The difference between `assert` and `require` is in *how much* gas is consumed. `assert` (or `throw`) consumes the remainder of the gas limit set in the transaction, while `require` (or `revert`) only consumes the amount of gas already used.

As to when to use which: `require` is always friendlier in terms of gas consumption. I have not seen a compelling reason to use `assert`.

The (weak) argument [I've seen](https://media.consensys.net/when-to-use-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-61fb2c0e5a57) is that it's nice to differentiate between things that are expected to happen versus things that aren't so static code analysis can help prove that it's impossible to reach `assert`s (but not `require`s) in the code. And if the `assert`s are truly unreachable, there's no downside to the extra gas consumption.